# Error when trying to use ViewChild annotation in Angular

Tags: angular, viewchild, angular-renderer2, elementref

I am trying to use ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild('hello', { static: false }) 
divHello?: ElementRef;
```

This is the template:

```
<div class="wrap" #hello>
Some test data
</div>
```

But, the ViewChild annotation is showing this error:

```
Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  This expression is not callable.
    Type 'void' has no call signatures.
```

Making the target ES5 is not my solution, since I don't want that in my case.

Is there any way to use ViewChild? I was referring to this tutorial: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/renderer2-angular/

Comment: Please always follow up to date documentation at angular.io https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 2):

In my case VSCode created a ViewChild function somehow (automatically? when I copy-pasted the @ViewChild annotation?). So check your code if there is a ViewChild function in you ts file and delete it.

Comment: yes that was the error to me